# Why won't this insurance calculator display output when it's run in Visual Studio 2012? (It debugs perfectly)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

Forgive me if I come across as amateurish, only been doing this for a few weeks. I have to build an application that calculates monthly insurance monthly and total premiums based on age, and insurance plan selected.

I made a few methods before the calcButton_click event, including;

i) ageCatTest to determine the age category the client belonged to.

ii) deductibleChoice to determine which deductible they would pay (0, 75, or 100). I figured putting all 3 in a listbox would be easier than trying to write code to contain answers outside those 3 options.

iii) planChoice to determine which plan has been selected (A or B). I also used a listbox to try and contain the realm of possible answers.

I set all the possible monthly premiums in a two-dimensional array, with row[0] corresponding to plan A and row[1] corresponding to plan B. Columns [0,1,2,3,4] correspond to the age category (ageCat). I then tried to set it up so the value was selected from the array using the result of the ageCat method and the planChoice method as index keys.

Lastly once the premium is determined it is multiplied by a potential discount (if the user selects either 75 or 100 as a deductible in the listbox, not 0).

The results of all this is supposed to be displayed in a few textboxes when the calcButton_click is activated, but this isn't the case. It doesn't freeze up or lag when I hit calculate, nothing happens.

Visual Studio cannot find any errors and as far as the compiler is concerned there are none. However, since nothing is happening I'm assuming there's something wrong with the way I've structured either the methods or the click_event, but I can't find any. If anyone can spot any obvious mistakes it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

```
namespace InsuranceApp
{
public partial class insuranceCalculator : Form
{
    public insuranceCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool planChoice(string plan)
    {
        bool planType = false;
        if (plan.Equals("B"))
        {
            planType = true;
            return planType;
        }
        return planType;
    }

    private decimal deductibleChoice(string deductibleSelect)
    {
        decimal discount;
        discount = 1;

        switch (deductibleSelect)
        {
            case "75":
                discount = 0.95m;
                return discount;

            case "100":
                discount = 0.92m;
                return discount;
        }

        return discount;
    }




    private int ageCatTest(int age)
    {
        int ageCat = 0;

        if (age >= 36 && age <= 45)
        {
            ageCat = 1;
            return ageCat;
        }
        else if (age >= 46 && age <= 55)
        {
            ageCat = 2;
            return ageCat;
        }
        else if (age >= 56 && age <= 65)
        {
            ageCat = 3;
            return ageCat;
        }
        else if (age >= 66 && age <= 75)
        {
            ageCat = 4;
            return ageCat;
        }

        return ageCat;
    }

    private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[,] plans = {{80, 90, 110, 140, 170},
                   {100, 110, 125, 170, 210}};
        int ageCat;
        int planType = 0;
        int age;
        decimal discount;
        string deductible;
        decimal coverage = 100000;
        decimal monthlyPremium;
        int months;
        string plan;
        decimal totalPremium;

        if (int.TryParse((ageTextBox.Text), out age))
        {
            if (age < 18 || age > 75)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you are ineligible for travel insurance.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (int.TryParse((monthsTextBox.Text), out months))
                {
                    ageCat = ageCatTest(age);

                    plan = planListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    if (planChoice(plan) == true)
                    {
                        planType = 1;
                        coverage = 150000;
                    }

                    coverageTextBox.Text = coverage.ToString("n2");

                    deductible = deducSelBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    discount = deductibleChoice(deductible);

                    monthlyPremium = plans[planType, ageCat];
                    monthlyPremium = monthlyPremium * discount;
                    premiumTextBox.Text = monthlyPremium.ToString("n2");


                    totalPremium = monthlyPremium * months;
                    totalPremTextBox.Text = totalPremium.ToString("n2");
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `VB cannot find any errors`?? That's C# code

Comment: I meant Visual Studio - sorry, it's been a long day. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I'm assuming you've set some breakpoints and maybe stepped through the code to check that the subroutines are all being executed in the order expected?

Comment: Best guess is that `int.TryParse…` is failing to parse the text in `ageTextBox.Text` or `monthsTextBox`, so the routine just exits. In these cases no error would occur but no output either. You can validate this by either using breakpoints or adding an `else` to the `if` statements and providing some sort of feedback, like `MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid age.");`.

Comment: Teach you a little tip for producing good code. Always have an ELSE for every IF.

Comment: I'm going to add in ELSE statements for them all, and go over my TryParse methods. Thanks everyone. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

> A general classification of computer errors would be: compile-time errors, run-time errors and logical errors.

I would agree with @Jay and @Steve. The issue here is more of a hidden logical error than a compile-time error. The absence of an 'else' statement after parsing the Textboxes means a 'silent-fail'. Rather raise an error in an appropriate else statement of use a try...catch block for the parsing and deal with the caught exception accordingly.

For the 'else' situation, a simple solution would look like (pseudocode):

```
if (try.parse (text box) == success) {
  execute program
}
else {
  message box show (relevant error message)
}
```

For the 'try..catch' situation, one simple solution would be (pseudocode):

```
try {
  parse (text box)
  execute program 
}
catch (Parsing Exception as e) {
  message box show (relevant error message)
}
```

Comment: I followed the consensus of the responses and it's running smoothly. It was indeed a logical error more than anything else. Thank you for the help!